# Can't print secure map service

Tags: arcgis-server, printing, map-service, arcgis-10.3

I just upgraded to ArcGIS server 10.3, and I still can't print with secure map service.

I embedded username and password in my web Application (visual studio .NET 2013 C#).

I saw this issue in the previous versions in the error list. But I thought they fixed this issue in 10.3 .
Does anybody else still have this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(worked with ArcGIS 10.1)

well.. I was struggling with this problem almost for a year now.
I just came up with a workaround.
The only thing you need to do is to generate a Short-lived Token every time your page loads. I did it in my Login Page and put it in Session.
I try to explain it step by step:

1-Generating a short-lived Token

- As you may know, Printing Tasks
     wont work with Long-lived tokens and Short-Lived Tokens will expire
     after a while ( you can set the lifespan in ArcgisManager/Security 
     ) . So you have to Generate Short-lived token server-side and save it in
     session.DONT DO IT
     CLIENT-SIDE(because you will expose the credentials and what's the
     point of securing the map in the first place!?). Here you can find how to generate tokens server-side
     [C# - Access content from ArcGIS Online](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104340/c-access-content-from-arcgis-online)

  2-Applying the short-lived token
- To avoid the Arcgis authentication windows dialog you have to
     setup your proxy.config and apply it to your esriconfig :

  ```
     esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "proxy/proxy.ashx";
     esriConfig.defaults.io.alwaysUseProxy = true;
  ```
- Then append the token to the end of your ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer
  address:

  ```
      var GeneratedToken = document.getElementById("HiddenTokenTB").value;
      var dynamiclayersURLForPrint = AGS_SERVICE_PREFIX + "/" + MAP_SERVICE_NAME + "/MapServer" + "?token=" + GeneratedToken;
  ```

  EDIT :
  I should say that you should make a Map object just for printing( with the token ). Dont add the token to the map you are showing( that will mess up your legend and TOC ). Before you are trying to Print the map , just pass the Map object that you made for printing.

Get the extent of the original map first.

printmap.extent = map.extent;

```
printer = new Print({
              map: printmap,
              templates: [template],
              url: printUrl
          }, dom.byId("printButton"));
```