# Error executing tool.: Layer "layer1" Unable to connect to map server

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-10.2, printing, proxy

I am using the [Configurable JavaScript Viewer](https://github.com/DavidSpriggs/ConfigurableViewerJSAPI), and have only changed a couple of the configuration settings.

One change I made was to use my own Export Web Map Task.

In viewer.js, I changed:

```
printTaskURL: 'http://maps.evansvillegis.com/arcgis_server/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task'
```

I then saw this note in the readme.md in the proxy directory:

> You will more than likely need a proxy page for printing and other large cross domain requests.

So, I set that up using the provided proxypage_net.zip files, proxy.ashx and proxy.config.

In proxy.config, I added:

```
<serverUrl url="http://maps.evansvillegis.com"
           matchAll="true"></serverUrl>
```

Then I made sure my viewer.js file pointed to the current proxyUrl:

```
esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = 'proxypage_net/proxy.ashx';
```

However, when I try to print, I am getting the following error in the response:

```
{"error":{"code":400,"message":"Unable to complete operation.","details":["Error executing tool.: Layer \"layer1\": Unable to connect to map server at http://maps.evansvillegis.com/arcgis_server/rest/services/BASEMAPS/BASEMAP_GOOGLE_WGS84_NO_FOOTPRINTS_BW/MapServer.\nFailed to execute (Export Web Map).\nFailed to execute (Export Web Map Task)."]}}
```

I have seen related posts:

[Secure Print Service Failed to Execute](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103639/secure-print-service-failed-to-execute)

[ArcGIS Online printing Unable to connect to map server?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102548/arcgis-online-printing-unable-to-connect-to-map-server)

However, the provided information (mind you, limited) was not much help.

**The 400 error - is this because my proxy is not setup correctly, or is there something wrong with my PrintTask service?**

This is the default PrintTask that is configured with ArcGIS Server 10.2.1.  The only other change I have made, is ensuring IIS users and the ArcGIS Server Account can access the ArcGIS Server directories.

Viewer: http://maps.evansvillegis.com/viewer

Comment: are your web application and print service even on different domains?  if not, a proxy shouldn't be necessary.  if you snoop the web traffic from within your app when printing, is the request even being routed through your proxy?  (ie: do you see traffic routed toward http://server/proxy.ashx?http://urlofprintservice)

Answer (score 1):

It might be the proxy setup, or it might be the code inside the JS you used.

There is a proxy parameter esriConfig.defaults.io.alwaysUseProxy. Try setting it to false.
You can read about the proxy page here: 
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/ags_proxy.html

Also you can add more serverUrls to your config since the basemap request goes to your defined server. The example is, for example, here: 
http://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/AnalyticsEnterprise/GISHelp/Lang_1033/topics/ESRIOnPremisesIntegration/ESRI_OnPremises_UseProxyServer.htm

Comment: Thanks for the links, but unfortunately I am not any further now than I was yesterday.  The alwaysUseProxy was set to false already, and I have already added the serverUrl to the config file.

Comment: there is no need to set alwaysUseProxy to true.  it would be better to let the API decide to use the proxy only when necessary (ie: when a print request is large enough to require a POST across domains.)